# ESP IDF4.3 showing ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, esp-idf-sys

i am facing below error for visual studio

```
ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file for esp-idf/libsodium/CMakeFiles/__idf_libsodium.dir/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_box/curve25519xchacha20poly1305/box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.c.obj: No such file or directory
[7/119] Building C object esp-idf/libsodium/CMakeFiles/__i...bsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_kdf/blake2b/kdf_blake2b.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

Please provide guideline for above problem